# Android Emulator not loading on netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I just downloaded the [android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/1.6_r1/index.html) sdk from the adnroid site and followed [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans) tutorial to set it up on netbeans. Everything to seem to have installed fine but whenever i try to run the application this window pops up:

[alt text http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/4327/androidemulator.png](http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/4327/androidemulator.png)

What I am assuming it asking me to choose the emulator, but it is not showing up on the list. Is there a reason why?

Comment: The dialog is to select an [AVD](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) - Android Virtual Device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't use netbeans, but it looks like you don't have any AVD's created, and if you do, then there is probably a way to associate them that you are missing in netbeans.  You can check here to create an AVD http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html

But I would just use eclipse if possible, the integration works really well, and it was written to run in eclipse, so there are less issues and hurdles.

Also see Running Your Application section of http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html  that will describe how to launch the app from the tools outside of the IDE.

Comment: I agree that Android development works very well in Eclipse.  I was primarily a Netbeans user prior to my experimentation with Android development with Eclipse.  I found Eclipse fairly easy to install and use.

Comment: How is eclipse easy to install? I am trying to install it for ages.... Being using all tutorials no luck! Any idea? I changed for Netbeans and I am basically on the same stage as the above question.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with you. But i have my emulator works now. 
Are you have to do is running your Android SDK Manager, then click Virtual devices, and Make new AVD device.
Click New. Then fill name, and select Target (Platform of your Android), Skin, and hardware. 
Then click Create AVD to finish.

Now you have device to choose. :)

Answer (score 2):

go in **C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe** and create the virtual device. After it appear in device list.
Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Open Sdk manager

Tool Manage AVD

Select and start AVD. wait open.

Goto netbean Run project.

U must see project run in AVD.

Success..

Answer (score 1):

The [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) at the link @broschb had posted is explaining how to create an AVD using command line. Do exactly what is says there (it's very easy). Once you have created the AVD it will appear in the AVD list in Netbeans. Actually, if you have only one AVD it will start by default when you run your app.

Answer (score 1):

run the avd manager which is location in the android-sdk folder and then create a new avd,but be sure you have already downloaded ARM EABI system image tool set.

Answer (score 0):

Just create avd (android virtual device) and run it..
like android -avd "name of your avd"

Then try to run your application.

It will ask you to select the virtual device that you have started above.
Thats it.